# Can KSQL/Kafka Streams support Complex Event Processing?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, complex-event-processing, ksqldb

I want to do user behavior analysis on events in kafka. Can KSQL/Kafka Streams support Complex Event Processing now?

Comment: Please elaborate more with specification.

Answer (score 1):

If 'Complex Event Processing ' in your question means implementing a complex business logic then the answer is yes.

You can implement the low level [Processor API](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html) of Kafka streams which lets you define your own transformers.

Btw, You can also chain this to existing topology along side Kafka streams DSL.

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box support. But it should be possible to use a CEP library (like Esper) via Processor API.